# Oracle SQL: Syntax for WHERE clause with one date between two others

Tags: sql, oracle, date

Apologies in advance, feel like I'm missing something fundamental here.

I'm limiting a query WHERE one field (already in date format) is between two others:

```
SELECT Stuff
FROM Table
WHERE datefield BETWEEN (currentdate - 28) AND (current_date - 1)
```

This returns nothing.  Now if I format both as dates explicitly and look for a single date:

```
SELECT Stuff FROM Table
WHERE TO_DATE(datefield, 'YYYY-MM-DD') = TO_DATE((current_date - 1), 'YYYY- 
MM-DD')
```

That returns the single day's results as intended.  However, if I then try something along the lines of:

```
SELECT Stuff FROM Table
WHERE TO_DATE(datefield, 'YYYY-MM-DD') >= TO_DATE((current_date - 28),'YYYY- 
MM-DD')
```

This returns the entire table, including dates from long before (current_date - 28)

And finally if I try the BETWEEN after explicitly formatting:

```
SELECT Stuff FROM Table
WHERE TO_DATE(datefield, 'YYYY-MM-DD') BETWEEN TO_DATE((current_date - 28) 
,'YYYY-MM-DD') AND TO_DATE((current_date - 1) ,'YYYY-MM-DD')
```

This returns nothing again.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Your queries are missing single quotes all over the place and would not even run.  Please format your queries as I have done for the first one.

Comment: Apologies, typos corrected, any advice on the question itself?

Comment: It would help if you showed the actual types of datefield and current_date. That said, first try doing your date calculations on actual dates by moving the `- 28` and `- 1` out of the TO_DATE functions.

Comment: Applying `to_date` to `current_date` or  a `date` column is nonsense. If `datefield` is actually a `date` the 1st query is correct. A common mistake is wrong order of values in Between (in your example it's correct)

Comment: Can you verify both the data type and values in `datefield` - presumably it's a date, but are the years correct? You're relying on implicit conversions so I wouldn't be entirely surprised if you've accidentally stored values with the wrong year (or century, at least). If so your second query would return data, if your `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` uses RR for the year...

Comment: @denoeth that's what I thought too, but the query returns nothing.

Comment: @Alex Poole - datefield is a date and the years seem to be correct (the range runs from May 2016 to present day), so it seems just plain weird at this point.

Comment: So `to_char(current_date - 1, 'SYYYY-MM-DD')` gives you values like `' 2018-10-23'`, and other dates in the last 28 days? I'm not sure how to explain all of the results if so... Out of interest what is your `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` set to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT Stuff
FROM   Table
WHERE  datefield BETWEEN (currentdate - 28) AND (current_date - 1)
```

Will return values between the 28 days before the current date at the same time of day as now and 1 day before the current date at the same time of day as now. So, if you run this at `10:23` today then it will get results before `10:23` yesterday and if your results for yesterday were all entered in the afternoon then they will not be included in the results.

```
SELECT Stuff
FROM   Table
WHERE  TO_DATE(datefield, 'YYYY-MM-DD') = TO_DATE((current_date - 1), 'YYYY-MM-DD')
```

`TO_DATE( date_string, format_model )` takes a string as the first argument so Oracle will implicitly convert your date to a string using the `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` session parameter. So your query is effectively:

```
SELECT Stuff
FROM   Table
WHERE  TO_DATE(
         TO_CHAR(
           datefield,
           ( SELECT VALUE FROM NLS_SESSION_PARAMETERS WHERE PARAMETER = 'NLS_DATE_FORMAT' )
         ),
         'YYYY-MM-DD'
       )
       =
       TO_DATE(
         TO_CHAR(
           (current_date - 1),
           ( SELECT VALUE FROM NLS_SESSION_PARAMETERS WHERE PARAMETER = 'NLS_DATE_FORMAT' )
         ),
         'YYYY-MM-DD'
       )
```

Firstly, don't ever rely on an implicit conversion. Secondly, depending on what your `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` session parameter is your query will either: raise an exception if the format model does not match `YYYY-MM-DD`; or give you gibberish dates (i.e. if your default format model is `RR-MM-DD` then you'll lose the centuries from your dates; if it is `DD-MM-YY` then you'll swap days and years - which might "work" [i.e. not raise an exception] for the next decade or so and then blow up horribly in February 2029); or it will work. However, this is a session parameter so users can change it and your query will randomly stop working without changing your SQL.

Assuming that your `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` is `YYYY-MM-DD` then this will effectively truncate your dates and you could do it much simpler using:

```
SELECT Stuff
FROM   Table
WHERE  TRUNC(datefield) = TRUNC(current_date - 1)
```

This will get all the results (regardless of time of day) for yesterday.

What you probably want is:

```
SELECT Stuff
FROM   Table
WHERE  datefield >= TRUNC( currentdate - 28 )
AND    datefield <  TRUNC( current_date )
```

As it will get all the results from Midnight 28 days ago to before midnight today.

---

If this doesn't work then you need to check your date values:

```
SELECT TO_CHAR( datevalue, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS' )
FROM   table;
```

You will possibly find that the dates are stored with the year in the 1st century AD (i.e. `0018-10-24 09:50:00` as the value) and this will (probably) be because dates were uploaded as a string with a 2-digit year (`YY-MM-DD`) when a 4-digit year (`YYYY-MM-DD`) was expected so Oracle will assume the century is 0.

Comment: Perfect, thanks a lot, not just for the answer but the underlying explanation of how oracle interprets the SQL, that's incredibly helpful for my future understanding.